# replacing values in a column in order to change Productivity Index Initial Value - R

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, transform

I am working on a time series analysis. I would like to analyze quarterly productivity data from 1971 to 2015. However, Productivity is expressed in Productivity index where 2010 = 1.

This mean that the average value of the 4 quarters of the year 2010 is equal to 1. This is considered the initial value. Increments or decreases of Productivity are then expressed with respect to this value.

```
> dput(head(prod_ts,179))
structure(c(0.4652, 0.4721, 0.4808, 0.4827, 0.4814, 0.493, 0.4936, 
0.5002, 0.5221, 0.5228, 0.5193, 0.518, 0.5058, 0.5152, 0.5193, 
0.5132, 0.5163, 0.5089, 0.5088, 0.517, 0.5269, 0.5229, 0.5279, 
0.5384, 0.5393, 0.5369, 0.5409, 0.5482, 0.5498, 0.5543, 0.5594, 
0.561, 0.5553, 0.5782, 0.5631, 0.5679, 0.5632, 0.5545, 0.5565, 
0.5545, 0.5552, 0.5599, 0.5707, 0.5742, 0.5787, 0.5884, 0.5916, 
0.5984, 0.6102, 0.6152, 0.6185, 0.6214, 0.6244, 0.6173, 0.6182, 
0.6247, 0.6304, 0.639, 0.6377, 0.6412, 0.6504, 0.6584, 0.6633, 
0.6736, 0.6753, 0.6815, 0.6925, 0.6937, 0.6995, 0.6978, 0.7034, 
0.7037, 0.7013, 0.6999, 0.6977, 0.6982, 0.7059, 0.7105, 0.7021, 
0.6992, 0.7016, 0.7051, 0.7098, 0.7187, 0.7285, 0.7436, 0.7518, 
0.7638, 0.7707, 0.7748, 0.7816, 0.7884, 0.7935, 0.8039, 0.8123, 
0.818, 0.8232, 0.823, 0.8284, 0.8266, 0.8345, 0.8359, 0.8399, 
0.8434, 0.8496, 0.8545, 0.8577, 0.8661, 0.8696, 0.8734, 0.8759, 
0.881, 0.8837, 0.8824, 0.8938, 0.903, 0.9101, 0.9131, 0.9129, 
0.915, 0.9218, 0.9266, 0.9323, 0.9324, 0.9371, 0.9392, 0.9467, 
0.9497, 0.956, 0.9603, 0.9689, 0.9747, 0.9744, 0.9782, 0.9788, 
0.977, 0.9814, 0.9916, 0.9977, 1.0141, 1.0108, 1.0109, 1.009, 
1.0116, 1.0214, 1.0243, 1.0276, 1.0304, 1.0295, 1.0212, 1.0097, 
0.9894, 0.979, 0.9861, 0.9883, 0.9898, 0.9982, 1.001, 0.999, 
1.0018, 1.0037, 1.005, 1.0146, 1.0144, 1.0168, 1.0088, 1.0171, 
1.0106, 1.0193, 1.0214, 1.0244, 1.0235, 1.0239, 1.0269, 1.0305, 
1.0347, 1.0309, 1.0383, 1.0358), .Tsp = c(1971, 2015.5, 4), class = "ts")
```

This is not very useful for my analysis. I would like the sum of the quarters in year 1971 to be expressed, such that their sum is 1. Then, all the remaining values of the time series (every quarter from 1972 to 2015) to be expressed as time series with initial value (1971,1).

Comment: Do u need `prod_ts[format(zoo::as.yearmon(time(prod_ts)), '%Y') == 1971] <- 1`

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `prod_ts / mean(prod_ts[1:4])` which scales the series so that the mean of the first 4 quarters is 1.

Comment: @akrun, thanks! This is what i need. However, i expressed myself little wrong. I would like to remain with quarterly data.. I want (1971,1) = 1 ...how do i need to modify your code?

Comment: Not clear for me.  If you want the first value of 1971, then `prod_ts[time(prod_ts) == 1971] <- 1`

Comment: @akrun I have edited the question. Does it make it more clear?.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want average of 1971 values (Q1 through Q4) to be 1 as it is currently for 2010. If so, this should fix it (assuming your data is in `df`:

```
 df/mean(df[1:4])
```