# Android Google Billing Library is not returning products

Tags: android, in-app-billing, google-play-console, android-billing, play-billing-library

My app uses Google Billing Library and it worked fine with my debug builds.
I was able to retrieve products and buy products with my licensed testers without having any issues.

Then I released the signed apk to the internal testers but the Google Billing library now returns an empty list from the `querySkuDetailsAsync`call, I see no products. There are no errors and `BillingResponseCode` is `OK`. What can be the reason for this issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: From my past experience: I once had different `applicationId` for debug and release builds, so for me, it wasn't working during debug builds.

Comment: @ashu for me it is vice versa. Debug works okay, there is a problem with the release.

Answer (score -2):

You need to add the `<application android:debuggable="true">` tag in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Edit `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` and add the following line just before the closing root tag of your AndroidManifest.xml file:

`<application android:debuggable="true" >`

This will enable your app to run in debug mode. See stackoverflow question for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47742068/google-billing-library-querygbskuasynccall-returns-empty-list

Comment: Link seems to be incorrect.

Comment: Link is not related.

Comment: Whoops, sorry! Here is the updated [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51876342/google-billing-library-querygbskuasynccall-returns-empty-list)

Comment: @PJMan0300 still incorrect.